# dialog box visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

On changing the dimension of dialog box with MoveWindow function , the dimension of inner content does not change . I mean that when I am changing the dimension of dialog box using movewindow or setwindowpos ,the button and other control which were inside it go out of border or change there relative position.

Is there any way which can resize the complete dialog box with its inner content (so that inner content also adjust themself with changing dimension).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should adjust content by yourself in `WM_SIZE` handler. If you want the framework to do this, consider the possibility of using [Qt](https://qt.nokia.com/products).

Comment: means i have to write the code to readjust the size of all the buttons, list , etc ..... which will be call when the size of dialog changes